# r ggmap geocode query max exceeded despite pay as you go?

Tags: r, google-maps, google-geocoder, ggmap, geocode

I'm using the `ggmpap` geocode function to geocode a long list of addresses.

I'm aware of google's 2500 free query limit, but I've signed up to pay as you go for additional requests.

I've used my API key in `register_google(key = [MyGoogleGeoAPIKey])`

Why do I still get the error message

> "query max exceeded, see ?geocode.  current total = 2500"

when I've reached 2500 queries?

I've also tried with `override_limit=TRUE` but that doesn't seem to do anything in my case.

Note my code worked fine for the first 2500 queries!

Comment: you can try my `googleway` package where you explicitly state your key inside the function call: `google_geocode(address, key = 'yourApiKey')`

Answer (score 3):

You have to enter your account_type and day_limit as parameter as well

```
register_google(key = "[your key here]", account_type = "premium", day_limit = 100000)
```

Please refer to this: https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap